# Hide Multiple Image data-id on load and Revealing them when Clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, quicksand

I currently have an image gallery with a filtering capability (Jquery Quicksand) which is in Wordpress. Each image in the gallery possesses a  `data-id` (eg `data-id="id-148"`).

I'd like to ask help on how to code on `jQuery`. I hope to have a multiple set of `data-ids` initially removed (or hidden) when the website loads then when I click on certain buttons (a `href`) with specific Class, these `data-ids` will then be showed.

Let's say `onLoad` of the website, the images with `data ids: 148, 149, 150` will be hidden then `onClick` of a button with a particular class `class="show"` then data-ids `148, 149, 150` will show. When I click `class="All"` the `data-ids` mentioned above will be hidden again.

The image is located in a list-item as such:

```
<li class="one-third column" data-id="id-148" data-type="Apples">
```

Hope to have some help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I just made some dummy element. Check this,

`HTML`

```
<ul id="quick-sand">
    <li class="one-third column" data-id="id-148" data-type="a">a</li>
    <li class="one-third column" data-id="id-149" data-type="b">b</li>
    <li class="one-third column" data-id="id-150" data-type="c">c</li>
    <li class="one-third column" data-id="id-151" data-type="d">d</li>
    <li class="one-third column" data-id="id-152" data-type="e">e</li>
    <li class="one-third column" data-id="id-153" data-type="f">f</li>
</ul>
<button class="showli">Show/Hide</button>
```

`JS`

```
var toHide = ['id-148', 'id-152'];
    $('#quick-sand li').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-id'), toHide) >= 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$('.showli').on('click', function () {
    $('#quick-sand li').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-id'), toHide) >= 0) {
            $(this).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6taY4/1/)!

```
This may help you to fix the cause.
```

Comment: Thanks Siva! I will try this out and let you know. :)